# How to use HTML5 video autoplay in combination with AngularJS ng-show?

Tags: angularjs, html, video

I want to show a video using the HTML5 video tag with autoplay within an AngularJS webapplication. I tried the following code:

```
<video ng-show="condition" autoplay ng-src="{{video.src}}"></video>
```

When the web application is loaded the video should not be shown (and started), which means condition is false. After the condition is changed to true, the video should start.
With the code above, the video is loaded, when the web application is loaded and it is hidden (which is fine) but the video is started immediately. Once the condition changes to true, the video is shown, but – since the video started already – it does not start at the beginning. Is there a way of pausing the video or reset the video, once it is shown?

Comment: use ng-if, it doesn't create the node. ng-show creates the dom element with display: none

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just found a workaround with the following code snippets below:

```
var startvideo = function(){
    angular.element('#video')[0].play();
};

var stopvideo = function(){
    angular.element('#video')[0].pause();
    angular.element('#video')[0].currentTime = 0;
};
```

with

```
<video id="video" ng-show="condition" ng-src="{{video.src}}"></video>
```

The first function starts the video and is called, when the condition changes to true. The second function is called if condition is set to false and pauses the video and sets it to the start.
Not sure though, if this is the best possible solution.

Comment: This is jQuery, not AngularJS.